# vlookup - greater than or equal to

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to create a gradebook in Excel using `vlookup` function. I am trying to match conditions (>=92, >=90, etc.) however I haven't been able to solve this problem.

How do I use `vlookup` to look for values greater than or equal to the reference?

[image]

`=VLOOKUP(B2, $E$2:$F$11, 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort your grading table lowest to highest, take out the >= signs so that it is actual numbers